# Tell csv to not separate the timestamp in csv row

Tags: python, csv

I'm currently trying to separate some information that I have in a csv file. All the information is separated via ':'. Here's an example:

```
    1234567890:0987654321234:Hino:Rei:Texas:07/12/2021 12:00:00 AM::
```

I'm trying to separate the values, but I don't want to include the timestamp after the date. Currently, I'm doing that like this:

```
read = csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter=":")
for row in read:
    print(row)
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
['1234567890', '0987654321234', 'Hino', 'Rei', 'Texas', '07/12/2021 12', '00', '00 AM', '', '']
```

The output I'm trying to get is this:

```
['1234567890', '0987654321234', 'Hino', 'Rei', 'Texas', '07/12/2021', '12:00:00 AM', '', '']
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix that? For some reason, RegEx come to mind, but I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: Your "CSV" is broken. Proper CSV requires that the value is quoted if it contains one or more separator characters. I.e., your data should be `1234567890:0987654321234:Hino:Rei:Texas:"07/12/2021 12:00:00 AM"::`.

Comment: Why are you using `:` as the separator in the CSV file in the first place? Use a separator that you don't expect to appear in the data.

Comment: @Barmar the reason is because i'm actually grabbing the data from an S3 bucket and that's how the data was input. It wasn't me who created the data. It originally was in a txt file, which I've converted to csv

Comment: @JustinEzequiel do you have any suggestions on how I can automate the rest of the rows to look like that?

Comment: Yes, use a csv.writer to create your CSV instead of writing it by hand.

Comment: "It originally was in a txt file, which I've converted to csv" - so your conversion is wrong. Post how you did it then we'll show you how to do it properly.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel not sure if me posting how I did it is now worth it since someone had posted a solution that works for me. I appreciate you though, thank you!!

Comment: That posted workaround will work only until you have to share your CSV with another developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to have a different delimiter in the csv file than `:` but if that is not possible.

You can modify your current output the following way:

```
# current output
output = ['1234567890', '0987654321234', 'Hino', 'Rei', 'Texas', '07/12/2021 12', '00', '00 AM', '', '']

# split thins up
first_part = output[:-5]
second_part = output[-5:]

# combine things back to date and time
tmp = ':'.join(second_part[:-2]).split(' ')
date = tmp[0]
time = ' '.join(tmp[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to your problem you could just process the output list according to your need:

```
read = read[:-5] + read[-5].split()[0] + [":".join([read[-5].split()[1]] + [read[-4:-2]])]
```

Notice that this is a workaround based on the data format, so you must be sure that all your csv follows that same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a row you can merge those elements of the array using a slice assignment:

```
read = csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter=":")
for row in read:
    row[5:6] = [':'.join(row[5:8])]
    print(row)
```